# In what segment does mmap allocate memory

Tags: mmap

I thought first that it was the heap, but it seems to allocate memory in a different place. radare2 tags it as folowing:

`0x00007fb07dacd000 - 0x00007fb07dace000 - usr     4K s rw- unk2 unk2`

Since it is not the heap, what do we call the segment where `mmap`ped memory is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure it has a name as universal as “heap” for the heap, but I’ve seen it called the “memory-mapped segment” or “memory mapping segment”; see [Do memory mapping segment and heap grow until they meet each other?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466443/86440) for one example.